# Cartesian product of sets

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two types of sets, one of them is a list of points of the form $\{t_{k}\}$ and the other one is an interval of the form $[a,b]$. And my custom set consists of these type of sets and I need to plot its Cartesian product.
As an example, say my set is $A=[0,1]\cup\{2,3,4,5\}$, I need to plot $A\times A$.
If I have only list of points, then I have no problem but when intervals come in to play,
I don't have a very good idea. I need help at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

For example, $A=[0,1]\cup\{2,3,4\}\cup[5,7]$.

```
points = {2, 3, 4};
intervals = {{0, 1}, {5, 7}};

Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, Point@Tuples[points, 2], 
  Rectangle @@ Transpose[#] & /@ Tuples[intervals, 2], 
  Line[{{{#1, #2[[1]]}, {#1, #2[[2]]}}, {{#2[[1]], #1}, {#2[[2]], #1}}}] & @@@ 
     Tuples[{points, intervals}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The disadvantage of the considered method is different width of lines and points. Adjusting the `PointSize` and `Thickness` does not help.

Let us consider another method and $A=[0,1]\cup\{3/2,4/3,\dots,(n+1)/n,\ldots\}$.

```
points = Table[(n + 1)/n, {n, 2, 30}];
intervals = {{0, Min[points]}};
```

I use `Min[points]` instead of `1` to remove the gap between interval and finite number of points.

```
min = Min[points, intervals] - 0.01;
max = Max[points, intervals] + 0.01;
size = 1000;
thickness = 2;
data = ConstantArray[0, size];
scale = Round@Rescale[#, {min, max}, {1, size}] &;
```

Here `0.01` is a small space around the data, `size` is the size of partitioning, and `thickness` measured in the integers units.

```
(data[[scale[#1] ;; scale[#2]]] = 1) & @@@ intervals;
(data[[scale[#] - thickness ;; scale[#] + thickness]] = 1) & /@ points;
img = ColorNegate@Image@Outer[Times, data, data, 1 - {0.33, 0.33, 1}];
```

Here `{0.33, 0.33, 1}` is color (light blue).

```
Graphics[{Texture[img], 
  Polygon[{{min, min}, {min, max}, {max, max}, {max, min}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: How can we make width of lines and dots same size? Also, what would you suggest for $A=[0,1]\cup\{3/2,4/3,\cdots,(n+1)/n,\cdots\}$?

Comment: @bkarpuz It is the interesting question. See my update.

Comment: I got the idea for filling the gap between the interval and the "cut" sequence. How about we use another set $B$ to fill the gap and take Cartesian product of $A\cup B$. For instance $B=\{1,31/30\}$ as a filler interval? But it seems that setting the size of the points and the width of the lines is the main issue.